# Where are my postgres *.conf files if I can't connect to server?

Tags: postgresql

I have a `PostgreSQL 11.10` installed from source code. When I try to start this DB instance it fall with fatal error. How can I find config files for this DB? `psql` can't connect to DB so, I can't run `SHOW config_file`

Comment: Did you do an `initdb`? If so the `*.conf` files will be in the directory you specified with `-D`.

Comment: Previous administrator could run `initdb`, but I don't know any location

Comment: Run ` pg_config`. The `CONFIGURE ... --prefix` line should tell you where it compiled to be installed. Unless the `initdb -D` was pointed outside the prefix the data directory should be there. Otherwise you will have to resort to using `find` to search for the files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try pg_ctl from the command line.  I am assuming Linux because you don;t specify:

```
$ pg_ctl status
pg_ctl: server is running (PID: 8787)
/usr/pgsql-11/bin/postgres "-D" "/data/"
```

The config files should be in the  location specified by the command output, in my case /data